# How do I specify 8^(a - b) in math mode

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

`$8^(a - b)$` produces only a superscripted `(`; the rest of the power is not superscripted.

How can I superscript the whole `(a-b)` portion?

Comment: Please read _any_ introduction to (La)TeX. The [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Put braces around the entire part that you want superscripted:

```
$8^{(a - b)}$
```

Note that from the mathematical point of view, the parentheses `()` are superfluous here and can be omitted:

```
$8^{a-b}$
```

Answer (score 1):

To always get it right you can define a command probably like

```
  \newcommand{\mpower}[2]{\ensuremath{#1^{#2}}}
```

For example:

```
  \mpower{8}{(a-b)}
```

Comment: In my opinion, such macro is un-useful. I always find the `\ensuremath` command mis-leading, because you should know if you are in math-mode or not. If any, I define `\newcommand{\upp}[1]{^{(#1)}}` and use it `8\upp{a-b}` ("upp" as "up--parenthesis")

Comment: I would in this case write the power as `\smash{(}a+b\smash{)}` because `()`'s in powers have a tendency to affect line spacing if used in the normal text.

Comment: The `\ensuremath` I only use it as a safety precaution. It is the first time I am seeing the `\smash` command. My answer, in no way is the best, but it may be an alternative to the norm, I guess.....